# Getting strange casing results in JSON when serializing using JavaScriptSerializer in .net 3.5 vb

Tags: asp.net, json, linq-to-sql, serialization, .net-3.5

Problem is simply that in the resulting json i sometimes get this:

```
{"success":true, "tests":[{"visningsNamn":"Test1","id":1},{"visningsNamn":"Test2","id":2}]}
```

And other times i get this:

```
{"success":true, "tests":[{"Visningsnamn":"Test1","id":1},{"Visningsnamn":"Test2","id":2}]}
```

The parameter Visningsnamn gets different casing from time to time. Seems random and no changes has been made in the code that gets the data and serializes it between the times the problem occurs:

```
 Dim tbl = From t In db.Guideinriktningars Order By t.Visningsnamn Ascending Select t.Visningsnamn, t.id

    If Not query = "" Then
      tbl = From t In tbl Where t.Visningsnamn.ToLower.Contains(query.ToLower)
    End If

Dim dataString As String = ""
    dataString = "{""success"":true, """ & root & """:"

   Dim s As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
    dataString += s.Serialize(tbl).ToString
    dataString += "}"
    c.Response.Write(dataString)
```

On the client side i use this info to popuplate a ExtJs Combobox like this:

```
{
fieldLabel: 'Inriktning',
xtype: 'combo',
store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
url: '_handlers/handleInriktningTexter.ashx',
editor: this,
root: 'inrs',
baseParams: { func: 'loadAll', root: 'inrs' },
fields: ['id', 'Visningsnamn']
}),
displayField: 'Visningsnamn',
valueField: 'id',
valueParam: 'id',
triggerAction: 'all',
forceSelection: true,
mode: 'remote',
emptyText: 'Välj inriktning...',
name: 'inrId',
id: 'inrId',
width: 250,
allowBlank: false
}
```

I set the param "Visningsnamn" in the code as displayParam and when it changes casing it doesnt work in the JsonStore or in the combo as displayParam since the json returned from the server isnt named in the same way.

Any idéas or thoughts on what that is going on that causes this are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Eldström
What is the problem that you are facing with this case sesitivity.
you may access the data at Client side using the index.like `this[1][0] and this[1][1]`.

Comment: Sorry i should have explained also what im doing on the client side. Will update the question with that info.